# Kubernetes - How can I confirm that my ingress controller is doing everything it should?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I've been struggling with my first kubernetes setup, and I can't work out where I've been going wrong. I have a .Net API that I've got working locally, and I can confirm that the Docker image runs without a problem locally. But when deployed into a Kubernetes service I only ever get a 404 from Nginx and that the certificate I have setup is invalid.

I'm hosted in azure, and am building and publishing to the ACR fine, and the deployment is being run by a CICD pipeline and pulling the correct image.

These are the files I have so far:
Deployment.yaml (the placeholders are pulled in by the CICD):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mywebsite-api-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mywebsite-api-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mywebsite-api-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mywebsite-api-container
        image: ${acrLoginServer}/${repository}:${imageTag}
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mywebsite-api-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mywebsite-api-pod
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: ClusterIP
```

ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mywebsite-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - api-uat.mywebsite.com
    secretName: mywebsite-tls
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: mywebsite-api-service
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: api-uat.mywebsite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: mywebsite-api-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.crt: /notpasted/
  tls.key: /notpasted/
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-06-06T17:47:27Z"
  name: mywebsite-tls
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "2795660"
  uid: 
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

The certificate I have is a wildcard, and I've pointed my DNS entry to the correct IP address, so I'm assuming that bit is configured correctly at least.

Any idea where I'm going wrong, the certificate being delivered by k8s is the standard Acme cert, and every request I make is returned with a 404. I'm not using Helm as it seemed overkill for this, but perhaps it's not?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to this myself. I didn't understand how nginx was setup, and that it runs as a pod itself in a different namespace.

From that nginx pod, I could view the logs and identified the following entry:

```
I0606 17:34:42.990421       8 store.go:425] "Ignoring ingress because of error while validating ingress class" ingress="default/mywebsite-ingress" error="ingress does not contain a valid IngressClass"
```

I could then run the following command to get the ingressClass name:
`kubectl get ingressclass -A -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: IngressClass
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: "2023-06-04T11:38:58Z"
    generation: 1
    name: webapprouting.kubernetes.azure.com
    resourceVersion: "2997218"
    uid: 8547e63e-30f7-4dfe-910b-2f7dce8884a3
  spec:
    controller: k8s.io/ingress-nginx
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

And that class name I just had to add to my ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mywebsite-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: webapprouting.kubernetes.azure.com
  tls:
  - hosts
  etc. etc.
```